# How to teach kids the value of accepting loss and moving on using Aesop's fables or otherwise

Tags: teaching, books, morals

I work part time with a kids after-school group and sometimes use Aesop's fables (which I also love) to teach them various moral values and ideas.

Recently I've been trying to find a story (I'm looking for an Aesop's fable but I'm open to other options) that teaches kids that failure is a normal part of life, not to worry when we fail, and the importance of accepting our mistakes, learning from them, and moving on.

I work with a number of groups ranging from say 6 to 16 and they are Chinese kids (I'm in China) so their English is fairly basic.

Answer (score 1):

When I taught I often stuck to real world individuals the students would know, but that failed often before reaching stardom or fame. I usually mention; Michael Jordan (Tons of good inspirational videos on YouTube), J.K. Rowling (author tie-in for Aesop), Jay-Z, Katy Perry, Jim Carrey, Bill Gates (Windows or Xbox drop depending on the crowd), and Walt Disney because everyone knows those movies.

If you'd be willing to share the age group I'd be happy to share some content I've gathered on the subject over time.

Answer (score 0):

I work with a number of groups ranging from say 6 to 16 and they are Chinese kids (I'm in China) so their English is fairly basic. Also they wouldn't be familiar with the western "real world individuals" that you mentioned. Though it sounds like a great idea. I guess I should first educate myself on eastern "real world individuals" that Chinese people would relate to. I'd appreciate any materials or content that you have to share.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question - this extra (and important) information should be edited into the main question, so that other people answering will not miss it.

Comment: @Erik 'Derek' is experiencing multiple-account-login and probably can't (doesn't have enough rep to) edit the OP himself: another user should do that for him.

Comment: Derek, I recommend you read http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts then use the [contact form](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/contact) to merge the two 'Derek' accounts http://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/19824/derek and http://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/19865/derek

Comment: I also encourage you to create a registered account, which will enable you to gain reputation to eventually comment and vote (and so on) but also respond more easily to answers/comments from other users, and eventually accept an answer as the most correct

Comment: I'll be converting this answer to a comment on the other answer in a while, but wanted to leave it visible for a while so Derek will be able to see it. Just to be clear -- I'm not ignoring all the flags :)

Comment: @Erica I came across this answer in the First Posts queue. I don't know if this is something you can do, but if possible, it might be worthwhile to reset Derek's "first answer" flag when you convert this, so that his next answer will go into the queue.